# Exponential map on a sphere in spherical coordinates

Tags: manifolds, riemannian-geometry, tensors, smooth-manifolds, geodesic

Let $M = \{ (x^\varphi, x^\theta) : x^\varphi \in [0, \pi), \thinspace x^\theta \in [0, 2\pi) \}$ be a [manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemannian_manifold) with [metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemannian_manifold#Riemannian_metrics) $\mathrm{d}s^2 = (\sin x^\varphi)^2 (\mathrm{d} {x^\theta})^2 + (\mathrm{d} {x^\varphi})^2$ (that of an ordinary 2-sphere in spherical coordinates).

Let $x = (x^\varphi, x^\theta) \in M$ be a point on $M$ and let $v = (v^\varphi, v^\theta) \in T_xM$ be a vector on the [tangent space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_space) of $M$ at $x$. Let $y = (y^\varphi, y^\theta) = \exp_x(v)$ be the point on $M$ generated by the [exponential map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_map) of $v$:

[image]

It is the point at $t = 1$ on the [geodesic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic) $\gamma : t \in I \rightarrow y \in M$ such that $\gamma(0)=x$ and $\dot{\gamma}(0)=v$.

How can I find $(y^\varphi, y^\theta)$ in terms of $(x^\varphi, x^\theta)$ and $(v^\varphi, v^\theta)$, given this particular metric?

**Edit**

Using the metric

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
g_{\theta\theta} & g_{\theta\varphi} \\
g_{\varphi\theta} & g_{\varphi\varphi}
\end{array}
\right)
=
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
(\sin x^\varphi)^2 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{array}
\right)
$$

with inverse

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
g^{\theta\theta} & g^{\theta\varphi} \\
g^{\varphi\theta} & g^{\varphi\varphi}
\end{array}
\right)
=
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
(\sin x^\varphi)^{-2} & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{array}
\right)
$$

I was able to calculate the Christoffel symbols

$$ \Gamma^a_{bc} = \frac{1}{2} g^{ad} (\partial_b g_{cd} + \partial_c g_{db} - \partial_d g_{bc}) $$

with non-zero components

$$ \Gamma^\varphi_{\theta\theta} = -\sin x^\varphi \cos x^\varphi $$
$$ \Gamma^\theta_{\theta\varphi} = \Gamma^\theta_{\varphi\theta} = (\sin x^\varphi)^{-1} \cos x^\varphi $$

From the geodesic equation

$$\frac{\partial^2 x^a}{\partial t^2}+\Gamma^a_{bc}\frac{\partial x^b}{\partial t}\frac{\partial x^c}{\partial t}=0$$

it seems I have to solve the equations

$$ \frac{\partial^2 x^\theta}{\partial t^2} = -2 \cot x^\varphi \frac{\partial x^\theta}{\partial t} \frac{\partial x^\varphi}{\partial t} $$

$$ \frac{\partial^2 x^\varphi}{\partial t^2} = \sin x^\varphi \cos x^\varphi \left(\frac{\partial x^\theta}{\partial t}\right)^2 $$

Is there a closed-form, analytic solution for these, as a function of $x(0)$, $\dot{x}(0)$, and $t$?